# Book: dystopian future with games and sex changes

Tags: story-identification, books, dystopia

I am trying to recall a book I read quite a while back.

The book revolved around people that no longer faced death I believe as, of I remember correctly, one of the main characters was well over one hundred years old. There was no longer a need for people to work so instead people played games and did as they pleased.

Another random detail was that sex changes were very common and were performed on a whim.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This question would be stronger if you can add some more details.  You should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for asking good story identification questions.

Comment: SOLVED! The player of games.

Comment: Hi Zane. You can add an answer to your own question now you've identified the book.

Comment: Huh.  I would not have gotten there from the details here!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds to me like *The Player of Games*, by Iain Banks, published in 1988. 
 It is one of the best known of the author's *Culture* novels (which cover all sorts of different science fiction subgenres) and the second one he published.  It has been published with a number of covers, but this seems to be the most common one.

[image: *The Player of Games*]

The common setting of the *Culture* is [described by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culture_series) as follows.

> The Culture is a society formed by various humanoid races and artificial intelligences about 9,000 years before the events of novels in the series. Since the majority of its biological population can have virtually anything they want without the need to work, there is little need for laws or enforcement, and the culture is described by Banks as space socialism. It features a post-scarcity economy where technology is advanced to such a degree that all production is automated.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FnoK.jpg) Its members live mainly in spaceships and other off-planet constructs, because its founders wished to avoid the centralised political and corporate power-structures that planet-based economies foster.

The sex changes play a particular role in this novel, and they are mentioned in [this detailed review](https://digressionsnimpressions.typepad.com/digressionsimpressions/2018/06/on-games-and-society-on-iain-banks-the-player-of-games.html):

> Gurgeh's sexual and personal identity is remarkably un-fluid given the society he inhabits. (Sex changes and sexual preferences are very fluid.)  He is one of the very few in his society who has not never changed sex, or (being a man) has slept with a man.

Comment: Ha!  The answer appeared while I was writing this.

Comment: I love that book! I wish I'd known there was an edition with cover art as gorgeous as that.